# How do you convert this DES encryption code from Java code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, des

How can I convert this Java code to JavaScript?

```java
public static String getSignature(String skey, String iv, String data) throws Exception {
  IvParameterSpec Ⅳ = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes("utf-8"));
  DESKeySpec desKey = new DESKeySpec(skey.getBytes("utf-8"));
  SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
  SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKey);
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, Ⅳ);
  byte[] databyte = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("utf-8"));
  return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(databyte));
}
```

I tried it myself, and I got:

```js
  function getSignature(
    skey,
    iv,
    data,
  ) {
    const IV = Buffer.from(ivString, 'utf-8');
    const desKey = Buffer.from(skey, 'utf-8');

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', desKey, IV);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
  }
```

But I got an `ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_KEYLEN` error, because my key is not 8 in length. I'm guessing that my JavaScript code is missing this part of the Java code, but I don't know how to translate this part into JavaScript...:

```
  SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
  SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKey);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function getSignature(skey, iv, data) {
    const IV = Buffer.from(iv, 'utf-8');
    const desKey = Buffer.from(skey, 'utf-8');

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des', desKey.slice(0, 8), IV);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is that the skey is more than 8 characters.. and I'm getting a TS error on `const generatedKey = key.update(desKeyBuffer, 'utf-8', 'hex');`

Comment: I added desKeyBuffer.toString(), and the TS error is gone. but I'm having problem with the IV now, it says: ERR_CRYPTO_INVALID_IV

Comment: I got 8 characters for the IV, is this correct?

Comment: For the IV error, make sure that the iv parameter passed to the getSignature() function is a valid IV string. The IV should be 8 bytes (64 bits) long. Ensure that you're providing a valid IV value.

Comment: yes, it should be 8

Comment: The iv is 8 length in characters and the skey length is 16, but I'm not sure if it's valid or not because I just got them from a vendor. Do the iv and skey need to be a matching pair?

Comment: the more detailed error is `Invalid initialization vector`

Comment: if (IV.length !== 8) {
    throw new Error('Invalid IV length. IV should be 8 bytes (64 bits) long.');
  }
This block checks whether the length of the IV is exactly 8 bytes (64 bits) and throws an error if it's not.

Comment: I just console.log(IV.length), it prints out 8, but I got this error Invalid initialization vector

Comment: The IV (Initialization Vector) and the key do not need to be a matching pair in terms of their length. They serve different purposes in the encryption process.

The IV is used to ensure that each message encrypted with the same key has a unique ciphertext. It should be a random and unpredictable value of 8 bytes (64 bits) in length for DES-CBC encryption.

Comment: The key, on the other hand, is used to encrypt and decrypt the data. For DES, the key should be exactly 8 bytes (64 bits) in length. If your skey has a length of 16 characters, it's not a valid key for DES encryption. DES requires a key length of 8 bytes.

Comment: To resolve the "Invalid initialization vector" error, make sure that the IV you are using is a valid 8-byte string and that it is truly random and unpredictable. If you received the IV and key from a vendor, you may need to double-check with them if the values are correct.

If the IV and key provided by the vendor are not compatible with the DES encryption algorithm, you might need to reach out to the vendor for clarification or obtain the correct values.

Comment: actually I got the IV error in here:

Comment: const key = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', Buffer.alloc(8), '');

Comment: and when I changed it to const key = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', Buffer.alloc(8), IV); I got another error in const desKeyBuffer = Buffer.concat([desKey, Buffer.alloc(8 - desKey.length)]); because 8 - desKey.length is -8

Comment: To fix the "Invalid initialization vector" error, you need to pass the actual IV value to the createCipheriv() function instead of an empty string. Here's the corrected code:

Comment: const crypto = require('crypto');

function getSignature(skey, iv, data) {

  const IV = Buffer.from(iv, 'utf-8');

  const desKey = Buffer.from(skey, 'utf-8');


  // Generate DES key
  const key = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', desKey, IV);
  key.setAutoPadding(false);


  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', desKey, IV);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'base64');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return encrypted;
}

Comment: In this code, I removed the unnecessary line key.setAutoPadding(false) as it's not needed for the encryption process.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous response. The issue lies with the usage of Buffer.alloc(8 - desKey.length) in the code snippet.

To correctly handle keys longer than 8 bytes, you can truncate or derive a valid 8-byte key from the provided key.

Comment: const truncatedKey = desKey.slice(0, 8);

Comment: Added this line to truncate the desKey to the first 8 bytes using the slice() method. This ensures that the key used for encryption is always 8 bytes in length.

Comment: actually I thought about that just simply truncate the skey. and seems like that is the solution.  thank you!

Comment: I editted your answer and accepted it.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT